# Use links as variables

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple little html page for my games and stuff, and i have a random game chooser (when i click a button it displays a random variable) :

```
function rndGame(){

var game = new Array;
game[0]='Half-life\n(Casual)';<br>
game[1]="Minecraft\n(Casual)";<br>
game[2]="TF2\n(Casual)"<br>
game[3]="Rusty Hearts\n(MMORPG)"<br>
game[4]="A Farewell To Dragons\n(RPG)"<br>
game[5]="Dark Souls : Prepare To Die\n(RPG)"<br>
game[6]="Disciples III\n(RPG)"<br>
game[7]="Dungeon Siege II\n(RPG)"<br>
game[8]="Fallout III\n(RPG)"<br>
game[9]="Farcry III\n(RPG)"<br>
game[10]="Elder Scrolls III - Morrowind\n(RPG)"<br>
game[11]="Elder Scrolls IV - Oblivion\n(RPG)"<br>
game[12]="Elder Scrolls V - Skyrim\n(RPG)"<br>
game[13]="Counter-Strike : Source\n(Shooter)"<br>
game[14]="Tribes : Ascend\n(Shooter)"<br>
game[15]="Assassin's Creed : Brotherhood\n(Stealth)"<br>

rdmGame = Math.floor(Math.random()*game.length);
document.getElementById("gameBox").value=game[rdmGame];
}
```

But i want it so when a random game pops up, i can click on it and it will take me to a link. How would i go about that?

Comment: Not the solution: check the position of the <br> tags

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are changing the value of the element with ID gameBox. If that is an `<a>`, then you'll simply want to also set the href attribute on that `<a>`. So keep a second array, with the URL for each game, so that you can make the link work as you expect.

So at the start:

```
var url = new Array();
// ...
```

And then at the end:

```
var gameBox = document.getElementById("gameBox");  // assuming this is an <a> tag
gameBox.innerHTML=game[rdmGame];
gameBox.href=url[rdmGame];
```

Comment: And probably `textContent` or `innerHTML` rather than `value`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a link, I'm assuming you add one called gamelink.

```
var game = new Array;
game[0]={value: 'Half-life\n(Casual)',linktext:"http://something.com/other"};
...

var gamebox = document.getElementById("gameBox");
gamebox.innerHTML=game[rdmGame].value;
var gamelink = document.getElementById("gameLink);
gamelink.setAttribute("href",game[rdmGame].linktext);
```

You're also going to need to get rid of the random `<br>`s in your javascript.  Thats going to cause you problems.

Comment: Ah wait, i don't know if it will make a difference but the element 'gamebox' is a textarea, not a link

Comment: Ok then you'll need to assign it to a link instead

Comment: I'm incredibly nooby at this, but where would i put the gameLink?

Comment: The layout of it all so far is 
<script>
function rndGame(){
var game = new Array;
game[0]={value: 'Half-life\n(Casual)',linktext:"http://something.com/other"};
game[1]={value: 'frsfr',linktext:"http://google.com"};

var gamebox = document.getElementById("gameBox");
gamebox.innerHTML=game[rdmGame].value;
var gamelink = document.getElementById("gameLink);
gamelink.setAttribute("href",game[rdmGame].linktext);
}
</script>


<textarea id="gameBox" readonly></textarea><br>
<button onClick="rndGame()" id="game_button_2">Random</button>

Comment: You can put `<a class="gamelink">Link For Game</a> next to the button or wherever makes sense for your site.  Note that you shouldn't have a script tag inside a text area though.  You'll want to move the `<script>..</script>` to the top or bottom of the page.